# Irregular error warning: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars

Tags: runtime-error

My code contains some random steps and exponential expression (monotonic expression), which needs to find its root at the end. The `"RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars"` appeared occasionally. For example, 3 or 2 times it appeared when I run 5 times. Could you tell me what's going on here? PS: each time I can get the result, but it's just the warning makes me confused.

Comment: Great. Code? What is double_scalars? What random steps?

Comment: @MatrixTai Very good question. It's too complicated to show it here, and it's a pity I haven't found any simple example to show it here. It's there some general idea or case for this error type.

Comment: ...Still too lack of information. Are you handling some `double` in python? At least state some background. Or even just show the few lines throw you the warning.

Comment: Thanks, this give me a hint. "exponential+=(T_data[runs][0])*(np.exp(-(x)*(T_data[runs][1])))"  this part following the warning. [runs] is the iterate. T_data is a list, in which are ndarray with shape (1,2).Is this helpful for you?

Comment: It seems like you overflow the exp function, print the `-(x)*(T_data[runs][1]))` where caught error.

Comment: Thanks @MatrixTai, do you have any idea to handle this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible way to solve it, depends on your data.

**1.**

As you are handling some huge number and exceed the limit of `double`

To solve this, the method is actually quite mathematical.

First, **if and only if** `(T_data[runs][0])*(np.exp(-(x)*(T_data[runs][1])))` is always smaller than `1.7976931348623157e+308`.

As `a*e^(-x*b) = e(ln(a)-xb)`

Thus, `(T_data[runs][0])*(np.exp(-(x)*(T_data[runs][1]))) = np.exp(T_data[runs][0]-(x)*(T_data[runs][1]))`

Use `np.exp(np.log(T_data[runs][0])-(x)*(T_data[runs][1]))` instead.

**2.**

However, as you said you get the result everytime, it is possible that `(T_data[runs][0])*(np.exp(-(x)*(T_data[runs][1])))` is approaching zero, which is too small that double can no longer hold but cause no harm to save as `0`.

And you should change your code like this to avoid the warning.

```
temp = (x)*(T_data[runs][1])) > 709 ? 0 : np.exp(-(x)*(T_data[runs][1]))
exponential += (T_data[runs][0]) * temp 
## As ln(1.7976931348623157e+308) ~= 709.78
```

Comment: And I already tried the situation by using ' exponential+=np.exp(np.log(T_data[runs][0])-(x)*(T_data[runs][1]))', but this time the error warning becomes 'RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  exponential+=(T_data[runs][0])*(np.exp(-(x)*(T_data[runs][1])))'. So it's likely the case you said on situation 2. Still need your suggestion, since I don't know the meaning of the code for situation 2. Thanks!

Comment: @IvyGao, in numpy, exp and log is actually calculate in terms of Taylor series, thus log may come up with divide by zero in some situation. Is that's the case, dun use method 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it!